# Android gradle exclude does not work as expected

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am developing a React Native project and am using a third party library [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service). Inside the build.gradle file of that library, the version of play-services-location is defined as so: (refer to [this link](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/android/build.gradle) for the entire build.gradle file)

```
dependencies {
    def googlePlayServicesVersion = rootProject.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion') ? rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
}
```

Inside the build.gradle file of my project, I have the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"
    }
}
```

Inside the app/build.gradle file of my project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-geolocation-service')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0') {
      force = true
    }
}
```

Even though I have specified in the gradle file to use version 16.0.0 for play-services-location, I still get the following error after I ran `gradlew clean` then `gradlew build`:

> Execution failed for task ':react-native-geolocation-service:generateDebugRFile'.
>
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-geolocation-service:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
>
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0.

Why is gradle still looking for version 16.1.0 and not version 16.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

If You are going to check the release notes from [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

June 17, 2019

The release is

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0
```

October 2, 2018

The release was

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
```

So there was no release **Version 16.1.0** for **location**

Comment: yes, I understood there is no version 16.1.0 for location, hence I tried to force 16.0.0 in my build.gradle file using exclude and force = true. But for some reasons that I could not understand, gradle is still looking for 16.1.0